# Surface Deform with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a setup in geometry nodes that will deform clothes based on the shape of my avatar.

I can currently do this with a surface deform modifier like below - But I'm wanting to know if this modifier is possible to replace as a separate Geometry Nodes setup on my T-shirt?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Something like this is possible, but it would be more difficult to set up and use than a surface deform modifier (the bind would involve applying a GN modifier) and would have all the same limitations of a surface deform: it would require a bind, it would require consistent target topology.  Can I ask what problems you have with doing it with a surface deform that you're trying to get around by using GN?

Comment: yeah I figured it might be tricky...to anwser your question it would mostly just be for the convenience of not having to rely on unbinding/rebinding everytime I make a change to the avatar, and when bringing in new garments the same GN could be applied.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing it with GN, you'd still have a bind process (for every change in the target *and* for every change in the modified object-- so like, for a new piece of clothing.)